# Using underscore as string in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Sheets("East-1").Cells(j, 10).Value = "=VLOOKUP($E" & j & ",East!$C:$JX,VLOOKUP(CONCAT($C" & j & ""_"" ",J$4),Vl_formula!$E:$F,2,0),0)"
```

the above code is not allowing me to use "*" (underscore) in concat function
concat(Cj,"*",J4)
above is the formula i am trying to use

Comment: Use the `.Formula` property to assign a formula, not the `.Value`

Comment: Please be clear what the string value you are generating should look like. Type the `CONACT()` function string with `#` in place of `j` with code formatting so the reader understands what the desired output is.

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax error i guess
In formula of Concat

```
Sheets("East-1").Cells(j, 10).Value = "=VLOOKUP($E" & j & ",East!$C:$JX,VLOOKUP(CONCAT($C" & j & ",""_"" ,J$4),Vl_formula!$E:$F,2,0),0)"
```